# How to find maximum of candidates recruited for a year in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my table structure

```
Id  Date        Candidates
1   2013-04-07  16
2   2013-04-27  12
3   2013-10-22  13
4   2013-10-08  1
5   2013-10-24  9
6   2012-07-11  14
7   2012-07-14  5
```

I want dynamic query for finding maximum number of candidates recruited. I want result on the basis of maximum number of candidates on year wise and month wise and date wise. How to write query for this criteria in sql. Please anyone help me

The Output should be, If i need on month basis means the output for above data is,

the highest number of candidates recruited is on month-04 and the total is 28,
The output is Month-April and Candidates-28

I need output as on which maximum number candidates are recruited for above data.

Comment: put here your query that you tried!!

Comment: You should really add what you tried, and a desired result. Which RDBMS are we talking about? MySQL? Also, what column type is `Date`? A real date type or a string?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson RDBMS(MS SQL Server 2008) Column type is Date in Date Data type and Candidate in int Data type

Comment: @VijaykumarHadalgi I haven't try any query.. Please Give some idea for this

Comment: @user2918543 It's not very clear what you'd want as output. Could you please add an example with the data you've given as input?

Comment: @user2918543 show how the output should be(output format) as your question isn't clear?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I have added an example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A common table expression can get the date details, and then you'll just need a regular `GROUP BY` to get the correct result;

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT SUBSTRING(CONVERT(VARCHAR, Date, 112), 1, 4) year, candidates
  FROM recruited
)
SELECT TOP 1 year best_year, SUM(candidates) candidates FROM cte
GROUP BY year ORDER BY candidates DESC;
```

[An SQLfiddle to test with](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4c8f8/2).